# Align list items with variable height to bottom ul

Tags: html, css

I'd like to align a series of `li` items to the bottom of their parent, the `ul`. One of the tricky parts is: the `li` items require a `float: left` as well as the items being variable in height and width. Is there a way to achieve this without using a "hacky" method?

Here's my current code:

```css
ul {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: bottom; /* doesn't influence the list items because of the float: left. i thought i'd put it here anyways */
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li figure {
  /* determines the width & height of the list item */
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
}

ul li:nth-child(2n) figure {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img />
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img />
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img />
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img />
    </figure>
  </li>
</ul>
```

NOTE: The width of the `ul`'s width is variable and my design requires there to be no gap between the list items. This is what I'm looking to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Enzio, can you share a screenshot of expected result.

Comment: @SreenathPG I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See snippet, note that the fixed width on the `ul` means an even distribution of the `li` with `table-cell`, so you may need to work on that in regards to the "gaps" between the `li`. As you didn't specify how that is supposed to look I didn't try to solve it in any specific way.

I think this is the way to go to get a bottom align.

```css
ul {
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
  display: table;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li figure {
  /* determines the width & height of the list item */
  margin: 0; 
 padding: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li:nth-child(2n) figure {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img />
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img />
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img />
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img />
    </figure>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How would I go about the gaps? I'd like the items to be placed right next to each other.

Comment: the total width of your items must sum up to the width of the ul.

Comment: Unfortunately, the ul's width will be variable.

Comment: Run the updated snippet, if you remove the width of the ul it works fine as well.

Comment: Actually, this is perfect because I can wrap the ul inside a container and align the container instead. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

float is **not** compatible with vertical alignement.

- `inline-block` & `vertical-align` does :

```css
ul {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
}

ul li {
  /*float: left;*/
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:bottom
}

ul li figure {
  /* determines the width & height of the list item */
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
}

ul li:nth-child(2n) figure {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img />
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img />
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img />
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img />
    </figure>
  </li>
</ul>
```

- `display:flex` & `align-items` does :

```css
ul {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 400px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-end;
  
}

ul li {
display:block;
float:right;
/* whatevever float or display will be overide by flex model */
margin:1px; /* is efficent */
}

ul li figure {
  /* determines the width & height of the list item */
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
}

ul li:nth-child(2n) figure {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img />
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img />
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img />
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img />
    </figure>
  </li>
</ul>
```

- `display:grid`

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;}
ul {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(150px, 0));
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(150px, 300px);
  grid-gap: 1px;/* whatever */
  align-items: end;/* or align-self on children */
}

ul li {
  display:block;
  /* align-self: end; */
}
ul li:nth-child(2n) {
  grid-column: span 2;}

ul li figure {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
}

ul li:nth-child(2n) figure {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img />
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img />
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img />
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img />
    </figure>
  </li>
</ul>
```

- `display:table` of course